# Compilation fails when useRef is checked for optional

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig, ts-loader

I'M curious why compilation fails when the ? is present

`useRef` from React is used.

Below is the error at compilation:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   const ref = useRef(null)
|   const handleClickOutside = event => {
>     if (ref?.current) {
|       setFocused(ref.current.contains(event.target));
|     }
```

and if I remove the `?` in `ref?.current` compilation succeeds. What is going on, and  short of going `if(ref && ref.current)` what is the way forward. Is there a specific webpack plugin to use? `TypescriptDeclarationPlugin` is the only one at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Optional chaining was announced in version 3.7 of typescript. Are you using an older version than that?

Comment: Sitting on ^3.9.3 so thats a weird one.

Comment: Did you try to remove node_module and install again? Might be sitting on an old version in your node modules

Comment: Looks like its related to the monorepo / workspace setup going on. Using `lerna`and a few installs at module level instead of the x-mapping of deps at root.